# How does Spark join() work when indexes are on custom classes?

Tags: java, join, apache-spark, equals, rdd

I'm having a problem when using the method `join` in Spark. I'll report a short code example to better explain the problem.

I have a customized class that acts as a wrapper for the Calendar class.

```
public class CalendarWrapper implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5089608400685021565L;
private Calendar c;

public Calendar getC() {
    return c;
}

public CalendarWrapper(Calendar c) {
    super();
    this.c = c;
}

@Override 
public boolean equals(Object otherC) {

    if(otherC == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if(this == otherC) {
        return true;
    }

    if(this.c.equals(((CalendarWrapper)otherC).getC())) {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
}
```

I use this class to initialize to `JavaPairRDD<CalendarWrapper,V>`, and then I perform a `join` of the two. The following code shows my program, where I'm adding one single record in every JavaPairRDD, where the date of the two `CalendarWrapper` are set to the same.

```
public class JoinTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Initializing Spark Context");
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Join test")
            .setMaster("local[1]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    int year = 2016;
    int month = 1;
    int day = 25;
    int hour = 11;
    int minute = 5;
    int second = 0;

    ArrayList<CalendarWrapper> cal1 = new ArrayList<>();

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.clear();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
    cal1.add(new CalendarWrapper(c));

    ArrayList<CalendarWrapper> cal2 = new ArrayList<>();

    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.clear();
    c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c2.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    c2.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
    cal2.add(new CalendarWrapper(c));

    if(c2.equals(c)) {
        System.out.println("Time equals");
    }

    JavaRDD<CalendarWrapper> cal1RDD = sc.parallelize(cal1);
    JavaRDD<CalendarWrapper> cal2RDD = sc.parallelize(cal2);

    JavaPairRDD<CalendarWrapper, String> cal1PairRDD = cal1RDD
            .mapToPair(x -> new Tuple2<CalendarWrapper, String>(x,
                    "test"));
    JavaPairRDD<CalendarWrapper, Boolean> cal2PairRDD = cal2RDD
            .mapToPair(x -> new Tuple2<CalendarWrapper, Boolean>(x, true));

    JavaPairRDD<CalendarWrapper, Tuple2<Boolean, String>> cal2cal1Join = cal2PairRDD
            .join(cal1PairRDD);
    System.out.println("Join size " + cal2cal1Join.count());
    sc.close();
}
}
```

Now, in about nine every ten runs the result of the `join` is void, while in the remaining run it ends up with the expected result.  I've cleared the `Calendars` in order not to have problems with the milliseconds (I've put also a check to be exahustive, to be sure that the problem doesn't derive from the calendar comparison). I also created the `JavaPairRDD` with `String` and `Boolean` in order to check whether that might be the problem (and it isn't - I read somewhere that the `join` is implemented as a `union().groupBy().flatMap()`, and I was guessing if the `union` could cause problems). The nice thing is that, if I use `Calendar` instead of `CalendarWrapper`, everything always works fine. Then I tried to look at what was happening in the overridden `equals`, and apparently the system performs four comparisons, every time comparing the current object with `null`.

I tried to look at the Spark code but it's a little bit hard. I searched for information about how the `join` work, but without any luck. Probably I'm doing something super stupid, but it doesn't seem to work right now.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that you're having issues because you implemented a custom `equals` without `hashCode`.  In general, if you implement one, you should always implement the other.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs

> Note: when using custom objects as the key in key-value pair operations, you must be sure that a custom equals() method is accompanied with a matching hashCode() method. For full details, see the contract outlined in the Object.hashCode() documentation.

You want the hash code to be deterministic and based off of the time stored in `Calendar`.  You can probably just get away with calling the `Calendar.hashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to override also the `hashCode` method, that apparently is used during the `join` function.

Comment: Sorry, but what's the purpose of "answer your own question", then? I've a problem, I ask a question. The answer is (a possible) solution to the problem. So I reported the solution to my problem as an answer. Unanswered stackoverflow questions are problems without solutions, aren't they? If this is not the stackoverflow philosophy, I get it, but there's a semantic mismatch, sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're completely right.  I misread this as a comment and should have paid more attention.  If you add a bit more info I'll delete my answer, since yours is correct.

Comment: It's ok! My post was really brief and not precise. I think you wrote it better, so yours is the merit of it! It's ok like that!